# HERE API license key for iOS starter

Tags: here-api

I registered for a free account at [HERE](https://developer.here.com/) to try out their iOS starter. I downloaded their sample from https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples and trying to build turn-by-turn-navigation-ios-swift. I have added the appid and appcode from their developer website (screenshot below)

[image]

However, to initialize the HERE service you are required to provide a license key as well.

```
import UIKit
import NMAKit

let credentials = (
    appId: "I have this",
    appCode: "I have this",
    licenseKey: "Can't find this"
)

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        NMAApplicationContext.setAppId(credentials.appId, appCode: credentials.appCode, licenseKey: credentials.licenseKey)
        return true
    }
}
```

Could someone please point me in the correct direction in which I could find the license key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think starter SDK supports Navigation as per: https://developer.here.com/develop/mobile-sdks

Only premium SDK supports navigation use-case and uses the license key to gate the feature usage.